# Django restarted (trigger file change) on every request when using runserver_plus

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

Django always detect file changes on every request on development mode. it was restarting even though i didn't make any change at all on the code.

for a simple view this is not causing a problem. the process of rendering one page done before restart triggered. but if i have more complex logic in view, django restarted before the process of rendering a page completed.

is any body know is this an expected behaviour? and why this is happened?
how can i solve my problem? render a complex logic before django restarted.

Is there are a way to disable that false positive trigger of file change?

[image]

Comment: I am recently facing the same issue and it seems like something is up with runserver_plus. I created an issue on their repo here: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/1807

meanwhile, you can just use `runserver` and that would work as expected.

Comment: thanks @SanyamKhurana, used `runserver` as an alternative now. updating to latest Werkzeug master branch solved the issue. i got it from here [link](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-restarted-trigger-file-change-on-every-request-when-using-runserver-plus/19347/10)

Comment: I had the same issue when I just changed to a new laptop. I was using runserver instead  for sometime as alternative. Now I found that you can change the poller to 'stat' by setting RUNSERVERPLUS_POLLER_RELOADER_TYPE = 'stat' and things the work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for me it was because the werkzeug version i installed. Installing the latest werkzeug from their master branch has fixed the issue [disscussed here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-restarted-trigger-file-change-on-every-request-when-using-runserver-plus/19347/11)